# How to change the lightbox size in galleria? (Answer Provided)

Tags: size, lightbox, galleria

**NOTE**: This is both a question and a solution provided.

If you are using the classic theme in galleria photo gallery, you will notice that many things are configurable, but one thing, that seems to be fixed, is the size of the light box. This was very frustrating to me and it took me a while to dig out the setting, but it turned out that the solution is pretty simple - one code line change.

I wanted to post it for others, so they can adjust their lightbox size, and not go through the trouble I did.

**SOLUTION**:

1. Open the file - `galleryHelper/src/galleria.js`
2. Find this code line - `var r = Math.min( (w-60) / lightbox.w, (h-80) / lightbox.h );`
3. Change it to this - `var r = 1;`

**NOTE**: If you make this change, the lightbox size will be as big as the actual image size you are displaying. Think of this value 1, as equal to 100%. Therefore if you would like the lightbox to be 1.5 times bigger than the actual image, set the value to 1.5. Conversely, if you would like it to display only 80% of the actual image size, set it to 0.8.

Also, this code line is inside a section, which looks like this:

```
rescale: this.proxy(function(e) {

                var w = Math.min( this.width(window), lightbox.w );
                var h = Math.min( this.height(window), lightbox.h );
                var r = Math.min( (w-60) / lightbox.w, (h-80) / lightbox.h );
                var destW = (lightbox.w * r) + 40;
                var destH = (lightbox.h * r) + 60;
```

You can clearly see that a math formula is used to dynamically calculate the size for each image. If you would like a fixed lightbox size, then play with these values: `var destW`, `var destH`.

Enjoy!!!